# HTML / Javascript .. Button click calls two scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page, that shows two buttons... I only want 1 of the javascript functions called depending on the image they click...

Here is a picture of what I am talking about..
[image]

So, when I click on the first box... I get the correct javascript function called.

When I click the second box, it calls both of the functions.

Here is my code:

```
<td align="center" valign="center" onClick="submitRow1('<% =rsTemp1("Created") %>','<% =rsTemp1("CSN") %>','<% =rsTemp1("PartNum") %>','<% =rsTemp1("TicketNum") %>', '<% =rsTemp1("Liability") %>')" nowrap class="bodyTextTLR"><img src="images/Invoiced.png" />  

<align="center" valign="center" onClick="submitRow3('<% =rsTemp1("Created") %>','<% =rsTemp1("CSN") %>','<% =rsTemp1("PartNum") %>','<% =rsTemp1("TicketNum") %>', '<% =rsTemp1("Liability") %>')" nowrap class="bodyTextTLR"><img src="images/NoInvoice.png" />
```

Comment: `<align="center"` isn't a valid element

Comment: Also you don't close your tags, which might be why your first click handler lies over both images and your second client handle only over the second.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image shows 2 images in one table cell, the way to do it is to have a `<td>` element containing the 2 images, and bind the click handlers to those images directly:

```
<td align="center" valign="center" nowrap class="bodyTextTLR">
<img onClick="submitRow1('<% =rsTemp1("Created") %>','<% =rsTemp1("CSN") %>','<% =rsTemp1("PartNum") %>','<% =rsTemp1("TicketNum") %>', '<% =rsTemp1("Liability") %>')" src="images/Invoiced.png" />  
<img onClick="submitRow3('<% =rsTemp1("Created") %>','<% =rsTemp1("CSN") %>','<% =rsTemp1("PartNum") %>','<% =rsTemp1("TicketNum") %>', '<% =rsTemp1("Liability") %>')" src="images/NoInvoice.png" />
```

Comment: Perfect, makes sense.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<TD>` tag is not properly closed with a `</TD>` tag. As a result, the click handler you've specified at the cell level is engaged for the contained elements. You should consider attaching the handlers to the `<img>` elements individually.

Comment: Thank you, basically the same thing as above.. very helpful thank you.